# Expression involving signed and unsigned types in c++

Tags: c++, expression

I'm studying the C++ language and one advice of my book is to don't mix in an expression signed and unsigned types because the signed type will be converted to unsigned.

For example :

```
unsigned int u = 10; 
int a = 42; 
std::cout << u - a << std::endl; // here the value will wraps around
```

After this program if I try to ceck the type of a with typeid the result is int, why ? 
Why the type of a is not more unsigned but it returns to int ?

Comment: No, what the book means is that your last line is equivalent to `std::cout << u - (unsigned int)a << std::endl;`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The variable is not converted to unsigned. It's value is converted to unsigned for use in the expression. That is to say, when you do this:

```
std::cout << u - a << std::endl;
```

A temporary, nameless unsigned int is created from `a`, which is then subtracted from `u`. It is as if you had done this:

```
std::cout << u - (unsigned int)a << std::endl;
```

or this:

```
unsigned int __nameless__ = a;
std::cout << u - __nameless__ << std::endl;
```

Except that the `__nameless__` variable does not actually exist outside of that expression.

Comment: a temporary object is created whenever I evaluate an expression ornly when it is necessary to perform a type conversion?

Comment: @user3697275: A temporary object is created for any expression that isn't just returning a reference to an existing object. A type conversion is one of those expressions, so is the subtraction itself. So, `u - a` actually has two temporaries created. (1) The result of the conversion of `a` to an `unsigned int`, and (2) the result of the subtraction of that temporary from `u`.

Comment: what happens if the variable a has value -42 ? what happens when the compiler create an unsigned type temporary with a negative value ?

Comment: @PieroBorrelli: The value wraps around to a very large positive number. `UINT_MAX - 41`, to be exact. Assuming 32 bit integers, that's `2^32 - 42`, or `4294967254`. Your operation`u - a` then ends up being `10 - 4294967254`, which also wraps around, and ends up being exactly equivalent to `10 + 42`.

Comment: is a temporary created also when i'm copying an object ? :

Answer (score 0):

The type of the variable doesn't change; when the expression is evaluated, the subexpressions may be converted or coerced to different types. So in the example `u - a` the subexpression on the right is converted to match the type of the subexpression on the left, but, conceptually, this is an invisible intermediate result that is of this other type, not the original underlying variable that is changed.